# Get IP addressses for pods in Kubernetes statefulset

Tags: c#, kubernetes

I'm using the [C# client API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp) and I'm trying to:

1. Get all pods associated with a given StatefulSet
2. Get the cluster IP address of each pod

I am aware of `Kubernetes.CoreV1.ListNamespacedPodAsync` and `Kubernetes.AppsV1.ListNamespacedStatefulSetAsync`. The part that I'm missing is how to

1. Know whether a given pod is associated with the StatefulSet
2. Discover a pod's IP address

Answer (score 1):

A feature of Kubernetes StatefulSet is *Stable Network Identity*. This requires that additional *headless Services* are created, in addition to the `StatefulSet` resource.

When this is done, you would typically access these instances by their **hostname** instead of using IP address directly. See [Stable Network ID](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id) for documentation about this.

E.g. after *headless Services* are created you could access 3 instances on these **hostnames**

- my-app-0
- my-app-1
- my-app-2

(when accessed from within the same namespace)